# How to write update all based on row value for date type column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have datetime column data type in `ReminderDetail` model, and I want to `update_all` values belonging to that column. I have written below query

```
ReminderDetail.update_all("reminder_date = date(reminder_date) - 1)
```

but it updates like below:

```
Before 2013-07-05 06:37:00 
After 2013-07-04 00:00:00
```

I want to update only the date, not hours. I want to like that 2013-07-04 06:37:00 or can I add some seconds to existing data ? can any one suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're casting the value to a `date` value, which strips off the time portion. You can use Postgres' `INTERVAL` method instead:

```
ReminderDetail.update_all("reminder_date = reminder_date - INTERVAL '1 day'")
```

Answer (score 0):

**date(remainder_date)** will select only the date part and you reduce it by 1. So here you date part becomes 2013-07-04 but since the time part has been stripped off, it insert zero's.
You can probably use **date_sub** sql method.

Change

```
ReminderDetail.update_all("reminder_date = date(reminder_date) - 1")
```

to

```
ReminderDetail.update_all("reminder_date = date_sub(reminder_date, INTERVAL 1 day)")
```

Using the **date_add** and **date_sub** you can modify year,month,day,hour,min,sec,etc.